# XSD: attribute for regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have an attribute in XML that contains regular expression:

```
<RegexPath regex="someRegex"/>
```

I want to make appropriate XSD for it:

```
<xs:complexType name="RegexPath">
    <xs:attribute name="regex" type="xs:regex??" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there a data type definition for regular expression in XSD? This is not something of survival importance, but it would be nice-to-have to be able to detect invalid regex via xsd validator...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, there is no regular expression that accurately matches all valid regular expressions (and nothing else). That's because the grammar for regular expressions is recursive, which means it's not a regular grammar (in the computer science sense of the term), which means it can't be described by a regular expression.

You could do it (with a trick) using assertions in XSD 1.1. The trick relies on the fact that an assertion that fails with an XPath error is treated as if the assertion is false. So the assertion

```
matches("", $value) or true()
```

fails if $value is not a valid regex, and returns true otherwise. However, you may need to do some further trickery to avoid a smart XPath optimizer mangling this. It's probably safe to write it as

```
if (matches("", $value)) 
then string-length($value) gt 0 
else string-length($value) ne 0
```

One minor caveat: this tests against the XPath regular expression dialect which is slightly different from the XSD regular expression dialect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive or built-in "regex" datatype defined by the W3C.
What is possible is to use regular expressions on the pattern face of simple type definitions.
What this means is that you could in theory create your own data type to validate the regular expression but it might be a quite complex implementation.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid. As XSD supports regex natively, I'd expect they provide build-in validation as a part definition as well... but it seems it doesn't work that way...